# Accidentally created a seperate /home profile

Tags: user-accounts, ubuntu-12.10

I've partitioned by Linux install to have separate / and /home partitions. In this instance, while installing Ubuntu 12.10, I accidentally created a new profile as /home. Thus, in the home folder on my system I have two different profiles. One is the one I always use and the other is new.

Is there any way to remove the profile I just made and have Ubuntu recognize my old profile as home?

This screen-shot should explain it all: http://ubuntuone.com/4yuZ24QnGBph2KSgvwbXG2
[image: SU535933 example]

Comment: So your current user id is dre with home directory /home/dre and you want user id andre with home directory /home/andre?

Comment: Precisely @parkydr

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a new user with the correct name and then log in as that user. You can either do this the GUI way through the system menus, or:

```
sudo useradd -UG sudo -p YOUR_PASSWORD andre
```

Then log out and log back in as "andre".

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. For some reason, creating a new account by GUI put me in a logout loop. I'll try the command line way. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Your original syntax was correct. It was 'sudo' not 'sudoers'. The account has been created but when I try to log in it says I have the wrong password. I feel close, am I doing something that is obviously wrong?

Comment: Umm, the password is whatever you wrote instead of `YOUR_PASSWORD` in the command.